# How can I center my google map on the city variable returned by geoip?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geoip

```
  var geocoder;
  var map;
      var MapCenter, map, x, y, z;

function geocode(address, callback) {
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var city=geoip2.city();
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
      callback();
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}


  function initialize() {
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var city=geoip2.city();
      var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 1,

      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);



geocode(city, function () {
  MapCenter = map.getCenter();
  x = MapCenter.lat(), y = MapCenter.lng(), window.z = 0;
  myLatLng=new google.maps.LatLng(x,y);


  }
```

This is what I have. As you can see the function geocode takes the city as an argument. The only problem is where to declare this city variable. As you can see I have tried doing it in the geocode function definition and the initialize function. both end up with an undefined result. Where am I supposed to declare this so that my geocode function runs without error?

OK upon further investigation, I think I have bigger problems. For some reason even the geoip samples are returning undefined values. for instance, the example on this page: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/javascript/. If you look at [www.supercuber.com](http://www.supercuber.com) and click view source you can see I added their example but the javascript isn't working correctly. Im not sure why this is.

Comment: Do you see any error in theconsole ?

Comment: yeah, I see ReferenceError: city is not defined on the line: geocode(city, function() {

Comment: Where does geoip2 come from?  Why are you using both it and the Google Maps Javascript API v3 geocoder?

Comment: I am using this: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/ library to get the browser city so that I can center the map on it. the geocoder is used to generate markers based on lat and long coords that I give it.

Comment: have you registered your domain  with them?

Comment: no I am just testing this script out so far.